# How to unconditionally stop a thread

Tags: java

Occasionally we must forcibly stop a thread as a best effort before entirely shutting down the whole JVM. Usually `Thread#stop` is cited as a surefire, even if ham-handed and deprecated, way to unconditionally stop a thread. This is not so, however: all the rogue thread has to do to keep itself running is catch `ThreadDeath` or a superclass:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  final Thread t = new Thread() { public void run() {
    for (;;)
      try { Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE); }
      catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getSimpleName() + ". Still going on...");
      }
  }};
  t.start();
  Thread.sleep(200);
  t.interrupt();
  Thread.sleep(200);
  t.interrupt();
  Thread.sleep(200);
  t.stop();
  Thread.sleep(200);
  t.stop();
}
```

This will print

```
InterruptedException. Still going on...
InterruptedException. Still going on...
ThreadDeath. Still going on...
ThreadDeath. Still going on...
```

Is there anything else that I could do to really, *really* stop a thread without killing the whole JVM?

Comment: I know it does not answer the question [but this is a good read on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) , it explains why stop was deprecated in the first place. Also, why would you have a 'rouge thread' that might be catching TheadDeath and interrupts in the first place? Threads are not meant for that. They don't provide security. The other thread could just as well terminate the JVM itself - or spawn other problematic threads.

Comment: This is somewhat an academic question; I just like to know exactly what each stopping technique does and what techniques there are in the first place. As a specific need presents itself, this kind of knowledge is what can save you.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I recommend submitting a simple answer of "no": there is no way to really, _really_ (forcibly) stop a thread without killing the whole JVM, and then linking to that article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no built in simple way to *really* stop a thread.

Such a method, destroy, [was planned but not implemented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy%28%29):

> *Deprecated.* This method was originally designed to destroy this thread without any cleanup. Any monitors it held would have remained locked. However, the method was never implemented. If if were to be implemented, it would be deadlock-prone in much the manner of suspend(). If the target thread held a lock protecting a critical system resource when it was destroyed, no thread could ever access this resource again. If another thread ever attempted to lock this resource, deadlock would result. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen" processes.

Threads are not meant for that. They don't provide security. The other thread could just as well terminate the JVM itself - or spawn other problematic threads.

For more information, [see Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) are deprecated. You can [read why here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: The argument resting on the non-implementation of `destroy` is a good one; as for other collateral comments, they are not particularly salient because 1. they have been common knowledge since at least the days of Java 1.4 and 2. because a responsible programmer may still want to kill a specifically targetted thread which is, for example, known not to mutate any shared state or hold any external resources.

Comment: Citing your reference: "We are not implementing [`Thread#destroy`] at this time, but neither are we deprecating it (forestalling its implementation in future). While it would certainly be deadlock prone, it has been argued that there may be circumstances where a program is willing to risk a deadlock rather than exit outright."

Comment: Another point: a thread may be robustly prevented from terminating the JVM, by installing a `SecurityManager`.

Comment: Related, there is a proposal to unconditionally disable Thread.stop in Java 8: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-May/thread.html#16974

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee that that thread can be stopped in Java. The most forceful way is Thread.stop but that's an accident waiting to happen. The alternatives are to use Thread.interrupt and having the thread check a flag but both of these rely on the thread being coded correctly and, in the case of the flag, checking it on a regular basis.

Personally, I would make sure I wasn't catching ThreadDeath. Stop is a poor way to stop a thread but at least you should get a notification as long as you aren't catching ThreadDeath.

Comment: I have never caught `ThreadDeath`, but I do routinely catch `Throwable` because I often want to know that a routine is completing abruptly for whatever reason, and also to preserve a top-level run loop.

Comment: Marko, if the code really catches Throwable and just keeps going, never checks interrupted (or a flag), then that's the code's fault, not Java's.

Comment: @user949300 Once you have ill-behaving foreign code in your project, it will be of little consolation to find out it is not Java's fault.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the last resort is to modify foreign bytecode so that it can't escape thread death.